# Getting oauth2 token with Angularjs returns me No 'grant_type' included in the request

Tags: django, angularjs, oauth-2.0

i try to get a token from my django-rest-framework api and an angularjs client.

This is how i use the get token access:

```
var payload = {
                  username: 'seb',
                  password: 'aa',
                  grant_type: 'password',
                  client_id: consumerKey,
                  client_secret: consumerSecret 
                };

                var r = $http.post('http://localhost:8000/oauth2/access_token',
                payload);
                r.success(function(response){
                    console.log(response.token);
                });
```

I've updated my headers like this:

$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';

unfortunately it returns me `{"error_description": "No 'grant_type' included in the request.", "error": "invalid_request"}`
playing with curl returns me the desired token :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One would expect the payload to be able to exist as a Json object... but alas it requires formData type content. The clue was in your line

> 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';

Hence OAuth provider is expecting the data as form based. So your payload would need to be this:

```
payload = "grant_type=password" + "&username=seb" + "&password=aa" +
          "&client_id=" + consumerKey +
          "&client_secret=" + consumerSecret;
```

Comment: thansk i found the solution too :)

Comment: Glad to hear it! Spent a number of hours on this myself!

Comment: If you are using jquery, you can make the playload by $.param(payloadInDict)

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple HttpService implementation I put together.

```
angular.module("services").factory("HttpService", ["$q", "$http", function ($q, $http) {

var httpSvc = {};

httpSvc.Url = "";
httpSvc.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
httpSvc.JsonPayload = {};
//execute login
httpSvc.HttpPost = function () {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    appLogger.conlog(httpSvc.JsonPayload);

    //Http Post method
    $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: httpSvc.Url,
        transformRequest: function (obj) {
            var str = [];
            for (var p in obj)
                str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
            return str.join("&");
        },
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": httpSvc.ContentType
        },
        data: httpSvc.JsonPayload //post data
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        deferred.resolve({ data: data, status: status, headers: headers, config: config }); //result
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        deferred.reject({ data: data, status: status, headers: headers, config: config }); //result
    });

    appLogger.conlog(deferred.promise);

    //return the callback promise
    return deferred.promise;
};

return httpSvc;

}]);
```

**Just inject it into a module and use it like so**

```
var oauth2Payload = {
                grant_type: "password",
                username: userName,
                password: password,
                client_id: appConfig.clientId
            };

            httpSvc.JsonPayload = oauth2Payload;
            httpSvc.Url = sysConfig.tokenUrl;
            httpSvc.HttpPost().then(function (response) {
                var data = response.data;

                appLogger.conlog("access_token:\r\n" + data.access_token);
                appLogger.conlog("refresh_token:\r\n" + data.refresh_token);

                $cookies.refresh_token = data.refresh_token;
                appLogger.conlog(data);

                deferred.resolve("ok");

            }, function (errResponse) {
                var data = errResponse.data;
                appLogger.conlog(data);

                deferred.resolve("error");
            });
```